# Probability - Screening of locals

Tags: probability, statistics

**Problem:**

In a community with 30.0000 locals there are 3 newspapers A, B and C.

In a screening it was discovered that:

- 12.000 reads A,------- 7000 reads A and B,
- 8000 reads B, -------- 4500 reads A and C,
- 6000 reads C, -------- 1000 reads B and C,

  ---------- 500 reads A, B and C ----------

How big is the probability that a randomly chosen local in the community reads:

- at least one of the newspapers A,B,C?

**Solution:**

[image]

**Question:**

In my attempt for a solution, I am trying to figure out the number of locals that reads the newspaper. Then, divide that number with the total number of locals, ie 30.0000. I start with the group that reads A, then subtract the locals that A share with B and C. My final answer, (12.5/30),  is not correct. The correct answer should be: (14/30) = 0.47

Anyone here with a better idea for a solution?

Comment: Have you heard of the inclusion-exclusion principle?  $|A\cup B\cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|$

Comment: The punchline is that your calculations, you attempted to say "Take what is in $A$, then add to that what is in $B$ that hasn't been added already, then add to that what is in $C$ that hasn't been added already"  You haven't accounted for what has/hasn't been added already correctly.  At the time of adding "What is in $B$ that hasn't been added already" that should have just been $|B|-|A\cap B|$ for an additional $8000-7000=1000$ being added at this step.  (*Recall that $A\cap B\cap C$ is a subset of $A\cap B$*).  Similarly, your last amount added is off

Comment: "7000 reads A and B" includes the possibility of someone reading A and B but not C as well as includes the possibility of someone reading A and B and C.  Your mistake seems to stem either from lack of care or incorrectly reading a phrase like "A and B" to have some implied meaning about C when it is not meant to have any such extra meaning.

Comment: Re: "*How about finding the amount for having read exactly one newspaper?*"  Subtract those amounts which were in multiple but keep track of "how many times" you wound up effectively subtracting the amount for all three and adjust by adding that amount back in enough such that the final result only effectively removed them once